# Adding unique elements to new list, one element isn't showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list = [1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 9]

my_list.sort()
print(my_list)
            
list2 = []    


for i in my_list:
    if my_list[i] not in list2:
        list2.append(my_list[i])
        print(list2)
list2.sort()

my_list = list2[:]
            

    
print("The list with unique elements only:")
print(my_list)
```

The code outputs 1,2,4 and then 9 from the new list in that order (missing the 6) any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: `for i in my_list` iterates over the _elements_ of `my_list`, not the indices. You probably want to use the element `i` inside the loop.

Comment: And `list2.append(i)`

Comment: This can be done more simply with `my_list = sorted(set(my_list))`

Answer (score 1):

Either you go with

```
for i in my_list:
    if i not in list2:
        ....
```

or:

```
for i range(len(my_list):
    if my_list[i] not in list2: 
        .....
```

you mixed it up. the first way is recommended in python. the weird result is because your `i` are numbers in the list, which you use as index (by mistake)

Comment: More recommended is to use a descriptive variable name: `for idx in range(...)` or `for item in iterable`.

Comment: true, i thought about changing that too, but then for comparison and making my point, stayed with `i`